# Dynamodb using partition key in a global secondary index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

New to DynamoDB, I have the partition *group_id*, and sort key *groupid_storeid_sortk*.

I am wanting to setup additional access pattern with the *group_id* and *store_addrss_sortk*.

Will this have any impact on performance using the partition key in the secondary index, or would it be better to create a new attribute as the secondary key, even though it would be duplicate data.

ThankYou

Answer (score 2):

It’s fine to use the same partition key attribute again as the PK for the GSI. No problem there.

For the future: You may want to watch some videos on single-table design and start using PK/SK as generic names since you might want to overload what’s inside them for different items. And then you might want GSI1PK/GSI1SK as the GSI keys.

That’s a style thing when you aim for some optimizations single-table design can bring.

Answer (score 1):

An index is simply another table that you don't have to manage yourself. When you create an index, the service (DynamoDB, for example) creates a new table for you and manages the synchronization of the data between the tables.

In DynamoDB you have two types of secondary indexes, Global and Local. If you use the same partition key, you can use both of these options. However, you have to define the secondary local index (SLI) when you create the table and you can't add it later. Only secondary global indexes (SGI) can be added after the creation of the table. You can read more about it in [DyanmoDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html).

Regarding performance, you need to consider the cost (read/write capacity) on top of the usual time considerations. You need to see if you are writing a lot to the table and not only reading a lot. Based on that you can plan carefully the projection of the data into the new index. Remember that writes are about 10 times more expensive and slower than reads. You can read more about [projection best practices here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general.html#bp-indexes-general-projections).